# Dataframes and Datasets in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am new to Spark and was going through Dataframes and Dataset. I was trying the understand the difference between them but I am confused.
I started [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-dataframe-and-RDD) and found that the abstraction of *RDD* happened in the following order.

**RDD (Spark1.0) —> Dataframe(Spark1.3) —> Dataset(Spark1.6)**

**Q.1** On the link [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-DataFrame.html), it says **Dataframe** is alias for **Dataset**[*Row*] i.e. *Dataset* of type **Row**. If *Dataframe* was the abstraction of *RDD* that was done first does that mean *Dataset* already existed from *Spark1.3* or when *Spark1.6* was developed *Dataframe* was redefined as *Dataset[Row]*?

**Q.2** On the link [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html), its says,

> "A Dataset is a strongly typed collection of domain-specific objects that can be transformed in parallel using functional or relational operations. Each Dataset also has an untyped view called a DataFrame, which is a Dataset of Row."

If, *Dataframe* is actually *Dataset[Row]* why is *Dataframe* called untyped? Isnt the type here supposed to be *Row* [defined [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html)]?

**Q.3** Also if *Dataframe* is *Dataset[Row]*, then why define *Dataframe* separately? Also every operation of *Dataset* should also be callable on Dataframe. If the statement above is not true or somewhat true please feel free to answer.

If these questions feel to broad, please let me know. I will edit them as required.

Comment: Whoever voted negative can you explain whats wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In short continuity of the external API (from Shark, now removed, through `SchemaRDD` and `DataFrame` to `Dataset[Row]`) doesn't mean internal continuity. The internal API went through significant changes and current implementation doesn't even resemble the initial Spark SQL attempts.

   There was not such thing as `Dataset` in 1.3, nor `DataFrame` has been unified with `Dataset` until 2.0.
2. That's hardly precise description (same as highly informal usage of "strong typing"). It refers to two facts:

   - `Row` being a container (collection-ish) of `Any` hence no meaningful *static* typing is possible. It doesn't mean that it is "untyped" (`Any` is a valid element of type hierarchy), but it simply doesn't provide useful information to the compiler.
   - Lack of type  checking at the `DataFrame` DSL level, which same as the other point is rather misleading, as it fully preserves type system constraints.

   So fundamentally it is "untyped" relatively to some idealistic, and not existent system, in which compiler protects for all possible runtime failures. In more realistic scenario it distinguishes between chosen implementation, and type oriented variants like frameless, which in turn are subject of some practical limitations of JVM as a platform (yup, I am talking about you, wide data).
3. > Also if Dataframe is Dataset[Row], then why define Dataframe separately? Also every operation of Dataset should also be callable on Dataframe.

   That's correct, but it doesn't imply the opposite. `Dataset[Row]` is *a specific case* of `Dataset` - it has to provide at least as much as `Dataset[_]` in general, but can provide more. And this is exactly the case.

   Additionally it is "a special case" to preserve backward compatibility, especially when "strongly typed" variant, is much less popular, and in general less efficient, than specialized `DataFrame` operations.